# File in Python Complex

Tags: python, file

I have this situation :

- *File1* named **source.txt**
- *File2* named **destination.txt**

**source.txt** contains these strings:

```
MSISDN=213471001120
MSISDN=213471001121
MSISDN=213471001122
```

I want to see **destination.txt** contains these cases:

MSISDN=213471001120 **only** for First execution of python code

MSISDN=213471001121 **only** for second execution of python code

MSISDN=213471001122 **only** for third execution of python code

I have this code:

```
F1 = open("source.txt", "r")
txt = F1.read(19)
#print txt

F2 = open("destination.txt", "w")
F2.write(txt)

F3=open("source.txt", "w") 
for ligne in F1:
    if ligne==txt:
        F3.write("")
        break

F1.close()
F2.close()
F3.close()
```

**source.txt** File is empty after first execution of code.

Thank's in advanced.

Comment: whatever the outcome, you're not writing anything to `F3`. And you're destroying your input by reopening it as output...

Comment: This may be better suited to ask on the Code Review exchange site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the whole file, before writing again, because mode `w` empties the file:

```
with open('source.txt') as lines:
    lines = list(lines)

with open('destination.txt', 'w') as first:
    first.write(lines[0])

with open('source.txt', 'w') as other:
    other.writelines(lines[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the current content of `destination.txt` before deciding what to write next.

This code worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

file_src = open('source.txt', 'r')
data_src = file_src.readlines()

file_des = open('destination.txt', 'r+') # 'r+' opens file for RW
data_des = file_des.read()

if data_des == '':
    new_value = data_src[0]
elif data_des == data_src[0]:
    new_value = data_src[1]
elif data_des == data_src[1]:
    new_value = data_src[2]
else:
    new_value = None

if new_value:
    file_des.seek(0) # rewind destination.txt
    file_des.write(new_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need an external file to store the state of "how many times have I run before"

```
with open('source.txt', 'r') as source, open('counter.txt', 'r') as counter, open('destination.txt', 'w') as destination:
    num_to_read = int(counter.readline().strip())
    for _ in range(num_to_read):
        line_to_write = source.readline()
    destination.write(line_to_write)

with open('counter.txt', 'w') as counter:
    counter.write(num_to_read + 1)
```

I've changed your calls to `open` to use context managers so you don't need to call `close` at the end.

I haven't run this code, so there might be some bugs. In particular, the case of `counter.txt` not existing isn't handled. I'll leave that up to you.